# Editing Already Added Documents

Tags: php

I have created this code to edit already added documents on my website.

The problem I have is that the document gets edited in the table but once it has been edited it creates a new duplicate of the document that was edited.

```
<script>
        var documentTable = null;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            documentTable = $('#documentTable').DataTable({
                dom: '<"row"<"col-md-6"B><"col-md-4"f><"col-md-2"l>><rtip>',
                ajax: '{{ baseUrl }}/users/api/{{ session.client.id }}/documents',
                columns: [
                    {"data": "id"},
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "description"},
                    {"data": "type", render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return data.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2').replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
                        }},
                    {
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            let html = '';
                            //loadForm parameters: api to retrieve modal form, target div id to load form to, row data, title of
                            html += '<button class="btn btn-primary small-button" onclick="showForm(\'edit\',\'{{ baseUrl }}/users/api/{{ session.client.id }}/documents/' + row.id + '\')">Edit</button>';
                            return html;

                        },
                        "sClass": "text-right",
                        "searchable": false
                    }

                ],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                responsive: true,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Create',
                        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                            let data = {};
                            showForm('create', '{{ baseUrl }}/users/api/{{ session.client.id }}/documents/form');
                        }
                    }

                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="form"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the function in PhP:

```
public function updateClientDocument($document, $documentName = null, $documentTmpName = null)
    {
        if (count($_FILES) == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (!isset($documentName, $documentTmpName)) {
            $documentName = $_FILES["document"]["name"];
            $documentTmpName = $_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"];
        }

        $mainDestinationFolder = UPLOAD_FOLDER;
        if ($document->file != '') {
            //delete old file
            unlink($mainDestinationFolder . "/client/" . $document->clientId . "/" . $document->type . "/" . $document->file);
        }

        $destinationFolder = $mainDestinationFolder . "/client/" . $document->clientId . "/" . $document->type;
        if (!file_exists($destinationFolder)) {
            mkdir($destinationFolder, 0700, true);
        }
        $fileExt = pathinfo($documentName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fileName = time() . rand(1, 10000) . "." . $fileExt;
        $destinationFile = $destinationFolder . "/" . $fileName;
        move_uploaded_file($documentTmpName, $destinationFile);

        $document->file = $fileName;
        $document->save();
    }
```

Any advice on what I can do to be able to edit the documents but not make a duplicated after.

Comment: I think your PHP file is creating a new record once you "marked" edit --- record creation will by default insert a new record. To fix the problem, you need to change the PHP script so that it will perform an update operation (instead of record insertion) when the same record already exists

Comment: @DarkBee I added the php function. I forgot to add it in the first place. Apologies. Maybe this will give more clearance.

Comment: @KenLee Added the function.

Comment: Great. So did you fix your problem ?

Comment: @KenLee Finally figured it out, was nothing to do with the function lol. Was a if statement error inside my twig file.